# MS SQL sorting records using values fetch by union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of records having values in MS SQL like

```
ID, Type, Name, Amount 
----------------------
1, 1, abc, 100
2, 1, xyz, 200
3, 1, aaa, 500
null, 1, 'Total', 800
4, 2, bbb, 100
5, 2, bbc, 200
6, 2, bbx, 400
null, 2, 'Total', 700
7, 4, ccc, 400
8, 4, cde, 200
9, 4, fgh, 400
null, 4, 'Total', 1000
```

Now I want to sort this values like 1000 should come in first, 800 in second like that and all the rows of id 4 should also come in first before other records.

MY Query was:

select Id, Type, Name, Amount from Table 
union all
select null, Type, 'Total', sum(Amount) from Table group by Type

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint: `ORDER BY Amount DESC`

Comment: I did: select Id, Type, Name Amount from Table union all select null, type, 'total', sum(Amount) from Table group by Amount order by Amount. But it will not put the records having max amount to top.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions in your `order by`

1. id 4 should also come in first before other records.
2. I want to sort this values like 1000 should come in first, 800 in second like that

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` and multiple `order by`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    ID INT,
    Type INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Amount INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 1, 'abc', 100        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 1, 'xyz', 200        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 1, 'aaa', 500        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (null, 1, 'Total', 800 );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4, 2, 'bbb', 100        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5, 2, 'bbc', 200        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6, 2, 'bbx', 400        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (null, 2, 'Total', 700 );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7, 4, 'ccc', 400        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8, 4, 'cde', 200        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (9, 4, 'fgh', 400        );
INSERT INTO T VALUES (null, 4, 'Total', 1000);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
Amount DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/950fef/1/0)**:

```
|     ID | Type |  Name | Amount |
|--------|------|-------|--------|
|      4 |    2 |   bbb |    100 |
| (null) |    4 | Total |   1000 |
| (null) |    1 | Total |    800 |
| (null) |    2 | Total |    700 |
|      3 |    1 |   aaa |    500 |
|      9 |    4 |   fgh |    400 |
|      7 |    4 |   ccc |    400 |
|      6 |    2 |   bbx |    400 |
|      5 |    2 |   bbc |    200 |
|      8 |    4 |   cde |    200 |
|      2 |    1 |   xyz |    200 |
|      1 |    1 |   abc |    100 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Amount]
  FROM [T]
  Group by [Type],[Amount],[Name],[ID]
  Order by [Type] desc, [Amount] desc
```

This is my result. I think you meant ordered by Type not ID

```
ID  Type    Name    Amount
NULL    4   Total   1000
7   4   ccc 400
9   4   fgh 400
8   4   cde 200
NULL    2   Total   700
6   2   bbx 400
5   2   bbc 200
4   2   bbb 100
NULL    1   Total   800
3   1   aaa 500
2   1   xyz 200
1   1   abc 100
```

Comment: in the above result, now i want 800 and its type to come on second and 700 on third.

Comment: try `Order by [Amount] desc, type`.whether I not sure, it correct or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the rows by the types with the largest total amount.  You can use window functions:

```
order by max(case when name = 'Total' then amount end) over (partition by type) desc,  -- put the types with the largest totals first
         type,  -- keep all types together
         id desc    -- canonically order within each type
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window function :

```
order by max(amount) over (partition by type) desc,
         amount desc,
         id;
```